# Получение текущего режима tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

В апи tinyMCE есть только установка режима. Например:

```
editor.setMode('readonly');
```

а как получить его текущее состояние?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам нашел ответ в сорцах:

```
let currentMode = editor.readonly;
```